# How to make all fields mandatory in a form and jump to next page only if all fields are filled?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am creating a form having multiple pages using angularjs,submit button is on last page and next and previous button is on all the pages. I want next button to be active only if all the fields in each page is filled by the user.User is not allowed to see the next page until all fields are filled on each page.

Comment: read up https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Answer (score -1):

apply this for field you want to validate

`<input ng-model="somefield">
<span ng-show="!somefield.length">Please enter something!</span>`